# mysql performance optimization for a subquery in select clause

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 tables (companies and companies_locations) and a very simple query

```
SELECT 
  c.name, 
  (SELECT MIN(ST_Distance_Sphere(l.coords, POINT(4.985173, 45.001672)) from companies_locations l where l.companyId = c.id
FROM companies c
WHERE MATCH (c.name) AGAINST ('+rand*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Note : longitude, latitude and fulltext are given via parameters in my code

Note : there may be multiple companies_locations for a given company (hence the min and subquery)

Now, my problem is : **I do not understand why mysql is not able to use a covering index for companies_locations(companyId, coords)**

Here are the sql details :

```
drop table IF exists companies;
drop table IF exists companies_locations;

CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx_ft_provider_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `companies_locations` (
  `id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `companyId` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `coords` point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_providerId` (`companyId`,`coords`(25)),
  KEY `idx_providerIdCoords` (`companyId`,`coords`(25))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO companies (id, name) ...;
INSERT INTO companies_locations (id, companyId, coords) ...;

explain SELECT 
      c.name, 
      (SELECT MIN(ST_Distance_Sphere(l.coords, POINT(4.985173, 45.001672))) from companies_locations l where l.companyId = c.id) as dist
    FROM companies c
    WHERE MATCH (c.name) AGAINST ('+rand*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The explain plan is :

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'c', NULL, 'fulltext', 'idx_ft_provider_name', 'idx_ft_provider_name', '0', 'const', '1', '100.00', 'Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'l', NULL, 'ref', 'idx_providerId,idx_providerIdCoords', 'idx_providerId', '162', 'beasyness.c.id', '1', '100.00', NULL
```

In the DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, I'd like the optimizer to choose idx_providerIdCoords and 'Using index: true'

Even if I delete the other index, the optimizer still seems to do a 'simple' ref (i.e need to go to the table to read the coords)

Comment: Do you have actual performance issues with it or it that you want to force MySQL into playing nice and use that index, and you will not stop before MySQL does? Because in general MySQL tends to optimize co-related subquery badly..

Comment: Besides `KEY idx_providerId (companyId,coords(25)),` the parted index `coords(25)` on a column which uses the point datatype it looks wierd.. Also let's talk about numbers how many companies are there and how many companies_locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost all cases, MySQL punts when it encounters a "prefix index" (`INDEX(..., coords(25))`.  Specifically, it cannot claim "Using index" since the index is not "covering".  That is, it may need bytes after the first 25.

Since `idx_providerIdCoords` and `idx_providerId` are identical, you should not expect the Optimizer to use one instead of the other.

The following *may* be an optimization for your case.  Change

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_providerId` (`companyId`,`coords`(25)),
KEY `idx_providerIdCoords` (`companyId`,`coords`(25))
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY(`companyId`,`coords`),
KEY (`id`)
```

This "clusters" on `companyId` (plus `coords`), thereby putting all the locations for a given company "next to" each other in the table.  It does, however, split up the `id` values.  (What the heck does `id VARCHAR(40)` look like?)